# alternate moving /hightlighting a control using x/y postioning

Tags: c#, user32

I'm looking for an api that can cause a windows select/highlight event to occur on a windows desktop, without actually causing the mouse cursor to move..  I can cause the  mouse cursor to move with :

```
public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

But that moves the actual cursor to that point...  I'm looking for a way to highlight only as one might do by using the tab and arrow keys to move around the windows desktop.  Any suggestions are appreciated..

regards,  rob

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for [SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can get a control's handle with Control.Handle or [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , and p/invoke SetFocus (use IntPtr as the argument type).

Comment: Thanks.  Those sort of work.  but my input (from a vendor SDK library) provides an x/y set of co-ordinance. I'd like to turn that into a control highlighting feature, leaving the mouse pointer where it is..  Any further thoughts?  thx.

Comment: @RobertFleming http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558(v=vs.85).aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632676(v=vs.85).aspx